# Dataframe with localized datettime index: Drop every row but those who exists in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe A like the following:

```
2018-01-02 09:35:00-05:00    1.238914e-01
2018-01-02 09:40:00-05:00    2.125115e-02
2018-01-02 09:45:00-05:00    1.969027e-02
2018-01-02 09:50:00-05:00    1.467054e-02
2018-01-02 09:55:00-05:00    1.831057e-02
2018-01-02 10:00:00-05:00    1.714546e-02
2018-01-02 10:05:00-05:00    1.515882e-02
2018-01-02 10:10:00-05:00    1.096963e-02
2018-01-02 10:15:00-05:00    9.687181e-03
2018-01-02 10:20:00-05:00    9.098983e-03
2018-01-02 10:25:00-05:00    8.747766e-03
2018-01-02 10:30:00-05:00    1.227635e-02
2018-01-02 10:35:00-05:00    9.554932e-03
2018-01-02 10:40:00-05:00    1.012054e-02
```

And another B like the following:

```
2018-01-02 09:35:00-05:00    1.95814e-01
2018-01-02 10:35:00-05:00    9.551878-03
2018-01-02 10:40:00-05:00    8.000478-03
```

I need to convert A in:

```
2018-01-02 09:35:00-05:00    1.238914e-01
2018-01-02 10:35:00-05:00    9.554932e-03
2018-01-02 10:40:00-05:00    1.012054e-02
```

That is: drop every row in A but those who exits in B.

So I am doing:

```
a_df = pd.read_csv(a_file, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
b_df = pd.read_csv(b_file, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

a_df.index = pd.to_datetime(a_df.index, utc=True)
b_df.index = pd.to_datetime(b_df.index, utc=True)
```

And finally

```
a_df = a_df.loc[b_df.index, a_df.columns]
```

But I am getting

```
 ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

pandas             0.24.2

Comment: Why not `a_df.merge(b_df, how='right')`?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind trying this:

```
#create some test data
dfa = pd.DataFrame({"index": ["2018-01-02 09:35:00-05:00", "2018-01-02 09:40:00-05:00", "2018-01-02 09:45:00-05:00", "2018-01-02 09:50:00-05:00"], 
                    "values": [1.238914e-01, 2.125115e-02, 1.969027e-02, 1.467054e-02]}).set_index("index")
dfb = pd.DataFrame({"index": ["2018-01-02 09:35:00-05:00", "2018-01-02 09:40:00-05:00"], 
                    "values": [1.238914e-01, 2.125115e-02]}).set_index("index")

#convert to date time object
dfa.index = pd.to_datetime(dfa.index, utc=True)
dfb.index = pd.to_datetime(dfb.index, utc=True)

#select to appropriate indices
dfa[dfa.index.isin(dfb.index)]
```

Output:

```
                    index   values
2018-01-02 14:35:00+00:00   0.123891
2018-01-02 14:40:00+00:00   0.021251
```

I am using `isin` on the index of `dfb` to achieve a boolean selection of the index of `dfa`.

Comment: It is working but dfa.index is returning: DatetimeIndex([          '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

Comment: @52gewg44 fixed, my bad. I am sorry!